# Android Firebase orderByChild query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently writing an Android application using Firebase. I have a product model which has a city attribute.
I am running the following query:

```
mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabaseReference.keepSynced(true);

productQuery = mDatabaseReference.child("products")
                   .orderByChild("city").equalTo(mCurrentUser).limitToFirst(100);
```

This query retrieves all products in the database regardless of the city.

I have spent the last four hours reviewing similar questions on SO and trying different combinations of the query functions + indexing on rules to no avail.
I have what I call a dumb solution which is re-duplicate the data under a city-products tree. However I am guessing that there is a better way leveraging orderByChild and I would appreciate if I could get some help to query the data by city.

Thanks for your input

Here's the CityFeed fragment - note: I checked mCurrentUserCity is set

```
public class CityFeedFragment extends BaseFragment {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private String mCurrentUserCity;
    private FirebaseProductAdapter mAdapter;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    private LinearLayoutManager mManager;
    private Query productQuery;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);
        mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabaseReference.keepSynced(true);

        retrieveCity();
        fetchProducts();

        mAdapter = new FirebaseProductAdapter(Product.class,
                R.layout.feed_item, ProductViewHolder.class,
                productQuery.getRef(), getContext(), false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mManager);


        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {
            fetchProducts();
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        });

    }


    private void fetchProducts() {
        productQuery = mDatabaseReference.child("products").orderByChild("city").equalTo(mCurrentUserCity);
    }

    private void retrieveCity() {
        mDatabaseReference.child("users").child(getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        if (user == null) {
                            showToast(getResources().getString(R.string.empty_user));
                        } else {
                            mCurrentUserCity = user.getCity();
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        showToast(databaseError.toString());
                        Log.w("Cityfeed", "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                    }
                }
        );
    }

}
```

Data structure
[image]

Comment: Can you please post a picture of your database structure, I'm not really understanding what your question is.

Comment: Also: please include the minimal code that reproduces the problem when reading the data. The code you now shared only creates a query, but doesn't retrieve any data yet. It's fine if you have a listener that does nothing more than logging the results, but I'd still like to see it.

Comment: done, thanks for taking a look

Comment: added entire fragment *

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have done everything except adding a listener for getting values as data snapshot. Please replace your method with this -

```
private void fetchProducts() {
    productQuery = mDatabaseReference.child("products").orderByChild("city").equalTo(mCurrentUserCity).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
            new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    //Map of all products which has city equal to mCurrentUserCity 
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            }
    );
}
```